# Android : Using Bluetooth APi

Tags: android

i am working on making bluetooth application which makes use of bluetooth api.

i am able to do it for version 2.0 or above but many newer Api of 2.0 are not supported in 1.6

So any help on what could be the solution.

**BluetoothAdapter** is available in 2.0 bt not 1.6 , so any alternate way of implementing it?
same with **Bluetoothdevice**

thanks in advance

Rakesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my company we are using this if the phone has installed the 1.6 version of Android.

http://code.google.com/p/android-bluetooth/

We check for the version of Android and use the above library with 1.6 and lower. With the 2.1 and above we use the official api that you are using.

I hope it helps you.